# RxJava2 Flowable distinguish the last element

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to process a `Flowable` in batches, waiting after each batch until some asynchronous work is done without blocking the thread, and to handle the last batch differently. Is there a better way than using an `AtomicReference` to cache the previous batch and process the last batch in `onComplete()`?

```java
      AtomicReference<List<Integer>> batchRef = new AtomicReference<>();
      Flowable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
              .buffer(2)
              .concatMapCompletable(batch -> {
                 List<Integer> previousBatch = batchRef.getAndSet(batch);
                 if (previousBatch != null) {
                    System.out.println("Regular batch: " + previousBatch);
                 }
                 // Something asynchronous would go here
                 return Completable.complete();
              })
              .subscribe(() -> {
                 System.out.println("Last batch: " + batchRef.get());
              });
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to react to stream events in a specific way. Most straightforward way is to create custom subscriber class which does exactly what you need:

```
static class MySubscriber implements FlowableSubscriber<List<Integer>> {
    List<Integer> previousBatch;

    @Override
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(List<Integer> batch) {
        if (previousBatch != null) {
            System.out.println("Regular batch: " + previousBatch);
        }
        previousBatch = batch;
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable throwable) {}

    @Override
    public void onComplete() {
        System.out.println("Last batch: " + previousBatch);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Flowable.just(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
            .buffer(2)
            .subscribe(new MySubscriber());
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe I should have made it clearer, but I can't use a `Subscriber` because I want to do some asynchronous work for each batch and only start the next batch once the asynchronous work is done -- hence the use of `concatMapCompletable` in my example.